# Issue in timestamp in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, timestamp

This is my table

```
[ID] [TIMESTAMP]
[1] [2013-12-19 01:17:35] []
[2] [2013-12-19 01:23:42] []
```

the time which is being shown here is different from my timezone. Lets say the time it is showing is 2013-12-19 01:17:35 but in my timezone the time is 2013-12-19 13:47:35.

My issue is that i want to fetch the time of my timezone not the default one.

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  change the timeszone in you MySQL. Just write query on you root file( may be index.php )
change the timestamp in MySQL. For tokyo

```
query("SET time_zone = 'Asia/Tokyo'");  //set your exact location
```

**Edit** 
make sure where you are? see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)
For more details to how set timezone? see  [how to set timezone of mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-timezone-of-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

It store in UTC, you can convert on receiving back to your local timezone

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo'); // your reference timezone here

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$date = /* SELECT date FROM database */;

$usersTimezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Vancouver');
$l10nDate = new DateTime($date);
$l10nDate->setTimeZone($usersTimezone);
echo $l10nDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: can I change the timestamp in MySQL? or I can do this only in php?